# usar los estilos de Bootstrap al imprimir una ventana con window.print()

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

lo que tratado de hacer es usar los estilos del Bootstrap para poder imprimirlos en una ventanita pero al parecer no los manda , y no me abre la ventana de impresión :

```
<script>
function printDiv() 
{
var divToPrint=document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');
var newWin= window.open('', '', 'height=900, width=800'); 
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html>');
newWin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,print" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
newWin.document.write('<body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body>');
newWin.document.write('</html>');
newWin.document.close();
setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple vista parece funcionar bien, tan solo un pequeño detalle que tienes que cambiar:

```
setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
```

ponlo así:

```
setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10000);
```

para que tengas al menos 10 segundos para verlo antes no se te cierre.

Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/nk1Lgtfo/

Comment: si, parece que era un margen de tiempo muy corto